# Android: Cell ID based location

Tags: android, android-source

Location based on LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER is based upon android sending the connected cell id to geolocation servers. This requires an active interent conncetion. Querying the cell id returns the approximate location of the tower stored on the server.

```
locationManager = (LocationManager) context.getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
    locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER, TWO_MINUTES, MIN_DISTANCE, mLocation);
    Location current = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER);
    if(current != null)
        Log.d("Location", "Lat: " + current.getLatitude() + ", Lon: " + current.getLongitude() + ", Acc: " + current.getAccuracy());
```

Using this code I can get the location from the server. However i want to understand the mechanism by which it does it.

Ive been searching the android source code where the system sends a request to the server for getting the location without any luck.

Ive searched the framework in location as well as services folder. Im coding for pre KitKat devices as KitKat with its fused provider has simplied the process.

Any help will be appreciated

Sahil

Answer (score 0):

The functionality is implemented in google play services wich is not open source and which requires an internet connection.

an android app can get cell-info updates through

```
 telephonyManager.listen(mListener, PhoneStateListener.LISTEN_CELL_LOCATION | PhoneStateListener.LISTEN_CELL_INFO);
```

where the answer comes from

```
PhoneStateListener mListener = new PhoneStateListener() {
    @Override
    public void onCellLocationChanged(android.telephony.CellLocation androidItem) {
        ....
    }

    @Override
    public void onCellInfoChanged(List<CellInfo> androidCellInfo) {
        ....
    }
};
```

I donot know how google playservices does the updating of the location. Maybe they have their own locationmanager-implementation

Comment: Okay so the function to get the location is in the googleplay lib. Thanks a lot.